# Finding the minimum of $x_1 + \cdots + x_n$ on ellipsoid

Tags: calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

> Let $A$ be a positive definite matrix $n \times n$ and $u^T = [1 \cdots 1]$. Use Lagrange multipliers to find the minimum of  $f(x) = u^Tx$ on $h(x) = \frac{x^TAx}{2} = 2$

This is what I did.

$$L(x,\lambda) =  f(x) + \lambda (h(x)-2)  = u^Tx + \lambda\bigg(\frac{x^TAx}{2}-2\bigg)  $$

$$\nabla_x L(x,\lambda) = \nabla f(x) + \lambda \nabla h(x) = u + \lambda Ax = 0  $$

Multiplying both sides by $x^T$:
$$x^Tu + \lambda x^TAx = x^Tu + 4\lambda  = 0 \Rightarrow \lambda = \frac{-x^Tu}{4} = \frac{-u^Tx}{4}$$

Substituting $\lambda$ in the first equation:

$$u - \frac{u^Tx}{4} Ax = u -  Ax \frac{u^Tx}{4} = 0$$

I got stuck here.

How could I finish it?

**Edit**

I noticed the following:

$$u -  Ax \frac{u^Tx}{4} = 0 \iff A^{-1} u -  x \frac{u^Tx}{4} = 0 $$

Multiplying both sides by $u^T$:
$$u^TA^{-1} u -  u^T x \frac{u^Tx}{4} = 0 \iff u^Tx = \pm 2\sqrt{u^TA^{-1}u}$$

Hence:
$$u -  Ax \frac{\pm 2\sqrt{u^TA^{-1}u}}{4} = 0 \iff  x = \pm \frac{2A^{-1}u}{\sqrt{u^TA^{-1}u}} $$

By inspection, the minimum is attempted at $x = - \frac{2A^{-1}u}{\sqrt{u^TA^{-1}u}} $

I think it solves the problem.

Comment: Hint: $A x u^T x = (A x) (u^T x) = (Ax) (u^T x)^T= (u^T x)^T(Ax) = u x^T A x$. And you know what the value of $x^T A x$ is.

Comment: Actually, it's $u^T x + \lambda(x^TAx/2-2)$. Our OP seems to be confusing $L$ with its gradient w.r.t. $x$.

Comment: You're right, I fixed the Lagrangian.